# How can I know if two different aggregations aggregated the same docs?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have two aggs:

```
   GET .../_search
   {
       "size": 0,
       "aggs": {
           "foo": {
               "terms": {
                   "field": "foo"
               }
           },
           "bar": {
               "terms": {
                   "field": "bar"
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Which returns the following:

```
   ...
   "aggregations": {
       "foo": {
           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
           "buckets": [
               {
                   "key": "Africa",
                   "doc_count": 23
               }
           ]
       },
       "bar": {
           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
           "buckets": [
               {
                   "key": "Oil",
                   "doc_count": 23
               }
           ]
       }
   }
```

My question is, how can I know if both "foo" and "bar" aggs are aggregating the same 23 docs?

I tried adding a sub agg to both "foo" and "bar" aggs to sum an arbitrary numeric field, but that's not remotely foolproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a subaggregation which aggregates the identity field of the documents, you can do this with terms or either composite aggregation. When using terms you need to provide a size. See this example:

```
GET .../_search
   {
       "size": 0,
       "aggs": {
           "foo": {
               "terms": {
                   "field": "foo"
               },
               "aggs" : {
                   "terms" : {
                       "field" : your_id_here
                   }
               }
           },
           "bar": {
               "terms": {
                   "field": "bar"
               },
               "aggs" : {
                   "terms" : {
                       "field" : your_id_here
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

You will need to compare the nested aggregations then.

Another approach would be to just filter out the desired documents using the search query.

Comment: Thanks, but there're two problems here. First, what if the number of documents is large? Large bucket sizes are either impossible or extremely wastful. Second, comparing each and every doc ID is really slow. There's got to be an elegant way to do this. For example, suppose there was a xor agg, which I could then use on the doc_ids.